# Unremovable android notification in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mobile, notifications

I need information how to block possibility to delete notification send by c# script in unity. I want send notification and delete it by script when user end sth on aplication. It`s sth like ticket, notification should be active as long as user have open ticket in game. Is any function how to set this. My actual code looks like this:

```
private void Start()
    {
        var channel = new AndroidNotificationChannel()
        {
            Id = "channel_ID",
            Name = "Notifications Channel",
            Importance = Importance.Default,
            Description = "Reminder notifications",
            LockScreenVisibility = LockScreenVisibility.Public,
        };
        AndroidNotificationCenter.RegisterNotificationChannel(channel);
        if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission("android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"))
        {
            Permission.RequestUserPermission("android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS");
        }

    }
    public void SendNotification()
    {
        var notification = new AndroidNotification();
        notification.Title = "Title";
        notification.Text = "Text";
        notification.ShouldAutoCancel = false;
        AndroidNotificationCenter.SendNotification(notification, "channel_ID");
    }
```

I was searching solution on documentation and yt, but I dont find any interseting info.

Comment: In native Android SDK you would use setOngoing(true). However as of Android 14 there was a behavior change causing such notification still dismissable unless it's a CallStyle notification.

Comment: But, I never create any nottifications on android before, and where I could use setOnGoing function? I dont see this function on my unity code editor

Comment: It might not be supported on Unity, unfortunately. You could write a custom native plugin but first try some 3rd party notification plugins - there should be something